# I can't suppress pg_restore output - why?

Tags: bash, postgresql, scripting, pg-restore

In my bash script that restores a Postgresql dump I am using:

```sh
pg_restore -d $db_name --clean --no-acl --no-owner $f >> /dev/null 2>&1
# or
pg_restore -d $db_name --clean --no-acl --no-owner $f 1> /dev/null
# or
pg_restore -d $db_name --clean --no-acl --no-owner $f 2> /dev/null
```

But I always get the same output - All errors and warnings are displayed.
Why are the redirections to /dev/null not successful?

Edit: The script runs inside a docker container

Comment: Is that a literal quote from your shell script or did you simplify it somehow?

Comment: This is one line of the script .. before this I am declaring $db_name and $f

Comment: I'm testing with pg_restore 12.2 with bash on Centos 7 and following redirections work `>> /dev/null 2>&1` and `2> /dev/null`. Redirection `1> /dev/null` does not work.

Comment: That's as expected - messages go to standard error. But that's not what you wrote in the question.

Comment: Try this `&> /dev/null` means all to /dev/null